# Basic polling protocol for offline/online status PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need a solution for determining online/offline status of each user of my website. My site is a singular page which doesn't have any links to click etc., and, for the most part, the user will simply keep the tab open for extended periods of time without really doing anything. The time the user goes offline doesn't need to be determined with too much accuracy, perhaps within ten minutes or so of them actually going offline.

Due to these criteria, I can't use the database solution for detecting user inactivity with timestamps, and I need to keep my site accessible to as many browsers and versions as possible, so web sockets are probably out of the equation. Javascript "onunload" and "unload" events don't seem to be able to pick up events such as unexpected system shutdowns etc. so aren't accurate enough.

I'm interested in setting up some kind of long polling script inside the index page which will send a PHP script a signal in intervals to let the server know that the user is still "alive" and using the page.

I need help writing the code, can anybody help?
It's mainly implementing a "listener" in PHP which I'm struggling with.

P.S I'm not sure if it changes anything, but once the user is determined to be offline, I need to run a small PHP script which I've already written which will remove some corresponding data from a JSON file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following advice from MadeInDreams and Sheepherder, I found a solution to my requirements.

Ajax call triggered in intervals to send a "still alive" signal in index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ping() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'json_update.php',
            data: ({signal:"1"}),
            success: function(data) {
                handleData(data);
            }
          });
        }
        setInterval(ping, 60000);
</script>
```

In json_updater.php:

```
if($_POST['signal'])
{
// update timestamp for user in json file from calling time() function.
```

json_maintainer.php:

```
// this script is called by a chron job on the server every 1 minute.
// it deletes all json entries with a timestamp which is older than time() - 
120.
```

This seems to be very accurate. To reduce load at the cost of accuracy, the ping frequency, and garbage collections can be adjusted accordingly.

Due to the json file being written to by two scripts possibly simultaneously, proper file locking is needed to prevent data corruption. If a database system is being used, this problem is negated by the queuing mechanics and doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is on the server side and there is no way that php will know what is going on on this page. You could used the time and set your users as off line after 5 minutes of inactivity. But since theres no link on your page to click, it will be hard to track activity.

An option would probably be to use a JavaSript on your page that will contact the server every 5 minutes to let you know that this page is still open in the client browswer. This will work even if the user is not actively viewing your page. You could go further and detect if the focus of the user is set on your page. So tabing out will make them loose focus on your page.

Comment: This is precisely what I need. I don't need to know if they tab out, only if they no longer have the page open at all.

Comment: Then a simple ajax call every X minutes to the server will do. When PHP print out the page. you could get the user ip and pass it to the javascript function that will make the call to the server. Note that you will have to use the ajax call to php to set users as offline as well since they will simply quit the page. So by using the time you will set all user as offline if the last call was more then 5 minutes ago.

Comment: Thanks, I already know how to set up the front end script which will send the messages to the server every x amount of time, it's mainly setting up a "listener" in PHP which I'm struggling with.

Comment: Ok so your ajax call will post something to a page.php.  In this page.php you will retreive $_POST['whatEverNameYouGaveIt'] and isert it inoto a database with a time field. You will also delete any entry wich the time value is greater then the time limit your javascript  ajax interval.

Answer (score 0):

If your page is a php page, you can collect the visitors ip address or computer name and store that in the database upon there browser accessing your site. Then set it to update that data every minute. The columns would be id, user, userlive.

The userlive would be updated every minute where user = 'ip or computer name'.

you would be updating by datetime or timestamp or your choice.

Comment: I already have the users "online" timestamps in a JSON file, but I don't see how I would remove the data once the user leaves the page?

Comment: You should use a simple database for that.